# Why is the X and Y axis on the mirror object not symmetrical

Tags: mirror-modifier

Recently I have return back to blender and try to make a pillar, however when trying to mirror a certain object, I used the [Mirror object] and set it to the pillars but instead of the object symmetrically mirroring in the X and Y axis, it instead mirror asymmetrically however when I add a cylinder in the same location as the pillar along with the same origin and 3D cursor it managed to mirror the object perfectly.

I Would like to know more on why this is happening as I suspect it has to be with the pillars.

[image]
Here pillar being used for as a base center for the mirror yet beside its location and origin being in the center it still manages to offset the object.

[image]
a cylinder that was added in the same X,Y location as the pillar yet it manages to perfectly have a symmetrical mirror on object

[image]
Top view with the pillars being the center for the mirror object

[image]
Top view with the cylinder being the center for the mirror object

I am also using simple deform and subdivision modifier on the object that I want to mirror however I cannot replace its origin without the simple deform modifier destroying the object itself.

Another note is that every object in all the photo here has not been rescale, rotated or even moved for each picture only the [Mirror object] from the mirror modifier was used in the pictures.

Comment: In your 3rd screenshot which has the pillar selected it is indicating in the Transform panel a Z rotation value of 6.5518°. Could this be causing the issue? Perhaps try Applying the rotation so that the Z = 0° .  To do that, in Object mode select the pillar object > CTRL A to open the Apply menu and choose the Rotation option. To be on the safe side best to save your work before trying this :)

Comment: In addition to @3fingeredfrog's comment, you say that "every object in all the photo here has not been rescale", but your first three images clearly show on the N-panel that both the mirror object and your original pillar object **have** been rescaled. While it might not affect the result here, you should apply the scale to both objects with Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode.